# php-lampp-ubuntu: include function doesn't work

Tags: php

I'm trying to learn include function but it doesn't seem to work, here is my code.

The file `count.html.php`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<title>Counting to ten</title>
</head>
 <body>
   <p>
   <?php echo $output; ?>
   </p>
 </body>
</html>
```

And this is my count.php:

```
<?php
    $output = '';
    for($count = 1; $count <= 10; $count++)
    {
             $output .= $count . ' ';
    }

    include './count.html.php';
?>
```

both are in the same directory

```
/opt/lampp/htdocs
```

the error on the browser

> Notice: Undefined variable: output in /opt/lampp/htdocs/count.html.php on line 9

Comment: What are errors you are getting?

Comment: Notice: Undefined variable: output in /opt/lampp/htdocs/count.html.php on line 9

Comment: Please show us the contents of `count.html.php` (the relevant contents , like line 9 and the code related to that line).

Comment: Change the extension to just `*.php` or `*.html`. And clarify the file names as well.

Comment: Are you sure that you r file name is count.html.php? I think it should be count.php. and if you are inlcuding from same directory, then you can directly include it by  include 'count.html.php';

Comment: @ChanjungKim - Why would that matter? Since that file clearly contains PHP, it _must_ end with `.php` and it doesn't matter if there's a `.html` before it.

Comment: @RohitMittal - Since the error message comes from that file, I would guess the file does get included (which it wouldn't be if the path or filename were wrong).

Comment: @MagnusEriksson if file is included properly, there is no error seems. Then it should be working fine. Either user calling only HTML file may be ?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson It is not related to error. But not a good naming. And also, it can confuse the questioner. This is not for the solution.

Comment: the centents of count.html.php is the first code above, and they are both in the same directory and I did include 'count.html.php' but it doesn't work. I'll try to change the extension

Comment: @ChanjungKim - Some developers prefer `foo.html.php` when the file also contains HTML and use `foo.php` if the file only contains PHP. That's just a matter of opinion and is off-topic for this issue.

Comment: I have checked the code from the book I'm learning several times before asking here, I tought It might have some relation with the version of PHP or xampp...

Comment: @ChanjungKim  I have changed the extension of the count.html.php to count2.php and also the value of the include to 'count2.php' and they are in the same directory but I'm still getting the same issue

Comment: @MagnusEriksson mostly agree with you on the file naming, but having a `count.html.php` _and_ `count.php` could still be problematic, if MultiViews is enabled I think …

Comment: I opened count.php in the browser instead of count.html.php, sorry guys for this blatant mistake and thank you so much for the rerplies

Comment: @04FS - Personally, I wouldn't use that naming convention for the reasons you mentioned and that it's (in my opinion) ugly. I would rather use a proper template engine with a MVC-architecture. I was just pointing out that renaming the file wouldn't solve anything and that I've seen people have that naming convention so the comment about it wouldn't solve the issue at hand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you read your error message carefully, it points you at the line 9 of the file ***count.html.php*** (obviously because you have less than 9 lines in ***count.php***).

That means either that

- the code you show us is not the actual code you test... then we really cannot help
- you access the wrong file

It is just impossible that the include fails, as you think, you have to rethink that hypothesis

If you get this error accessing ***count.php*** that means the include worked because the error points at the line 9 of a file that have less than 9 lines, so it points at the line 9 of the included file.

Most likely your are trying to access the file ***count.html.php*** directly from your browser, when you actually meant to access the other file ***count.php***, the one that defines the variable `$output`

Comment: That's exaclty what I'm trying to do, but the function "include" doesn't seem to work

Comment: No. There is no line 9 on the pure PHP file (cf your error) that means that you are accessing the wrong file

Comment: it refers to the line in the first file count.html.php where it declares the variable output, the only problem that varial get its definition from count.php. sorry if I can't clarify my problem properly, I'm still new to php

Comment: Read the answer again and rethink your hypothesis. If you stick yourself to the ”the include do not work“ one, you are loosing your time and won’t find your issue nor will you be able to explain it for us to help you

Comment: Thank you so much now I get it, I was trying to access count.php from the html file since I thougth html is the file meant to deal with the browser.